# Pyside2 second window(QDialog) closes the main one

Tags: python, pyside2

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load("mainWindow.ui", self)

        self.ui.pushButton_call_dialog.clicked.connect(self.call_dialog)
        self.ui.close()

        self.ui.show()


    def call_dialog(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.dialog = loader.load("dialog.ui")

        self.dialog.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Hi everyone,
any idea why the second (dialog) window closes the entire application?
Of course, it is not a crash since i'm getting a message saying:

> Process finished with exit code 0

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `window.show`? If it's an invocation of a method, then you forgot parenthesis.

Comment: the window.show works as it should even without parenthesis

Comment: @radham `window.show` does not do anything, remove it and observe the same behavior, instead if you use `window.show()` you will get another one.

Comment: This looks like a bug in pyside/pyside2. The equivalent code in pyqt5 works exactly as expected. That is, closing the dialog does not also close the main window. The bug seems to be in `QUiLoader`, because using a plain `QMainWindow` restores the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle your QDialog on a separate class, and then make them interact only, the structure might change a bit, but you can see if it's a viable answer:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        button = QPushButton("Dialog")
        button.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def open_dialog(self):
        dialog = MyDialog()
        dialog.show()
        dialog.exec_()


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        button = QPushButton("Close")
        button.clicked.connect(self.close_dialog)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def close_dialog(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    m = MyWindow()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Just notice that you should include the `setUp` step on each class.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To put the dialog into a separate class didn't work for either.
Every time the Dialog.close() event was called, it closes the whole application.

What worked for me, was to use hide() instead